# rail 4 coordinate isn't saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have model

```
class Building
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Geocoder::Model::Mongoid

  field :address,            :type => String, :default => ""            
  field :location,           :type => Array, spacial: {lat: :latitude, lng: :longitude, return_array: true }

  ## Building index
  index({location: "2d"})

  def latitude
    location[1]
  end

  def longitude
    location[0]
  end

  def latitude=( lat )
    location[1] = lat
  end

  def longitude=( lng )
    location[0] = lng
  end
end
```

this form in the view

```
= f.text_field :latitude
= f.text_field :longitude
```

and this is the controller

```
...
def create
  @building = Building.new(building_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @building.save
      format.html { redirect_to @building, notice: 'Building was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @building }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @building.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private
  def building_params
    params.require(:building).permit(:address, :latitude, :longitude)
  end
...
```

The latitude and longitude are populated in the form, but when I change the value and save it, it didn't work, even the other field like address is changed in the database. But it's working flawlessly in console

```
> b = Building.first
> b.latitude = -7.27094221115
> b.save
 => true
```

Comment: something like this? https://gist.github.com/spondbob/8953622

Comment: I need an input text to enter the lat and lng manually

Answer (score 0):

i think problem on `params`, from form you have `string` latitude and longitude, but need `float`.

Comment: where do I have to parse it to float?

Comment: `location[1] = lat.to_f` and `location[0] = lng.to_f` didn't work

Comment: sorry I didn't catch your point, if you're asking about the log here it's https://gist.github.com/spondbob/8953622

Comment: look this `"latitude"=>"-7.26961135864", "longitude"=>"112.70665740967"` you have `string` you need `float`. show controller create action.

Comment: try `params.require(:building).permit(:address).merge(latitude: params[:building][:latitude].to_f, longitude: params[:building][:longitude].to_f)` if not work try add bang to `merge!`